# Creating the game Snake on Netogo

Tags: netlogo

I have to create the game snake on Netlogo, with specific instructions on how the snake has to move, as below:

"The snake moves by adding a square to its head and simultaneously deleting a square from the tip of its tail."

I believe that I have successfully managed to fulfill this condition, however, when taking a sharp turn everything falls apart, due to lines 105-110. The issue is that I can't seem to figure out how to specify which body segment has to become the tail in the next step.

```
  ask heads [
if (count heads-here + count mice-here = 2) [
  if heading = 0 [
      hatch-heads 1 [
        setxy xcor (ycor + 1)
```

;;and so on for all 4 directions

```
ask heads [
  if heading = 0 [
    hatch-heads 1 [
      setxy xcor (ycor + 1)
```

;; and so on for all 4 directions

```
ask bodies [if (
  count bodies-on neighbors4) + (
  count heads-on neighbors4) + (
  count tails-on neighbors4) < 2 [
    set breed tails
    set shape "square"]]
```

;; the above segment is where I believe the problem lies

I am hoping for the last "body" segment on the snake to turn into the breed "tail".